# Thomson scattering: radiation scattered in one direction or all directions?

Tags: scattering, x-rays

I have a question about how Thomson scattering takes place. Say X-rays hit a bound electron in a crystal. (These electrons aren't "free", but the energy difference is so large that the scattering is modelled as if that of Thomson.) The radiation is absorbed for a tiny moment, and then released. But, how is the energy released? Is it emitted as a ray in one direction, as a cone at one angle, or as a "sphere" at all angles?

If the energy is emitted in a scattering cone, then, after many, many, many scattering interactions, the "sum" of all cones form a sphere?

I hope you understand my question.

Answer (score 1):

Thomson scattering is a "classical" process. An incoming *wave* from a particular direction induces an oscillation in the electron. If the incoming wave is plane-polarised then the electron oscillates along one axis and re-radiates (polarised light) as an oscillating electric dipole.

The radiation pattern from an oscillating electric dipole is *not* spherically symmetric. The scattered power depends on $\sin^2 \theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between the direction of scattered light and the oscillation axis.

If you are in a situation where you are deep inside a scattering medium, such that the radiation field is isotropic, then the scattered light will also be isotropic.

Comment: In the case of x-ray diffraction in a crystalline material, is the scattered light isotropic?

Comment: @AndersMB Obviously not, otherwise you wouldn't get X-ray diffraction patterns. This is an interference issue. The Thomson scatterers are at regularly spaced intervals.

Comment: I think I am way out of my depth in this. I thought the scattering which takes place in XRD analysis was Thomson scattering. I visualize a single scattering event as the as a scattering cone, with the apex at the origin. Inside the crystal, some directions of the cone go "into" the crystal, while some go outward. Those going outward then interfere, resulting in the constructive interference at certain angles as defined by Bragg's Law. How far off is this account? I appreciate your input!

Comment: @AndersMB As I said in my answer, Thomson scattering is not isotropic and neither is there a "scattering cone". You would probably get further by revisiting the reasons for diffraction of waves using the Huygens-Fresnel wavelet approach or even looking at some answers on Physics SE for how reflection works at a microscopic level.